# ¡opendir(), readdir(), como mostrar nombres de archivos con acento?

Tags: php

Quiero obtener los nombre de los archivos de una carpeta pero al momento de mostrarlos las letras con acento aparecen con un signo de interrogación.

Como puedo hacer para que aparezcan las letras con acentos?

Dejo el código de ejemplo.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $directorio = opendir("2015");
        while($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
            if(is_dir($archivo)){
                echo "[".$archivo."]<br/>";
            }
            else{
                echo $archivo."<br/>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza utf8_encode para convertir el nombre del archivo al sistema de caracteres utf8, que es el que estás utilizando en tu ejemplo:

```
echo utf8_encode($archivo);
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: eh puesto eso pero no salen los acentos, solo salen letras raras.